# Converting large data sets

Tags: excel, mysql-workbench, export-to-csv

newbie to the data world. Trying to convert an excel file to csv to import into MySQL workbench however, the dataset is too large and I end up losing data when converting to csv.

I ended up importing the excel file to google sheets to use in big query but I really liked using MySQL workbench and would like to be able to utilize it for larger data.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Converting excel to csv to import to MySQL workbench

Comment: Please provide a clear explanation- are you losing rows? Some columns getting misformatted? What is the original source of the data? If the data volume is not too large for excel itself, then it is not too large for excel to export to csv properly.

Comment: first I saved a .xlsx file as CSV UTF-8 
- error banner on top of the excel sheet:
Possible data loss. Some features might be lost if you save this workbook in comma-delimited format.
- When I open this csv in my mac default app which is numbers I get a warning:
   Your data has 85,172 rows and numbers cant support more than 65,353
- When I upload it straight to MySQL workbench through import wizard rather than viewing in app, it is greyed out an I cannot select the csv

Comment: secondly I saved the .xlsx file as 
  Comma Separated Values (.csv)
- I get the same error banner in excel, the same error in numbers
- I am able to select it for import from MySQL through table import wizard; I get errors saying: row import failed with error (data truncated…) and only 28,000 of the records were imported which took the whole night to import

Comment: it seems you need to split your excel file in multiple CSVs. You can do it manually, via a VBA script, or external tool. What would you like help with?

Comment: Hi Melman - please change your question to include the info in your comment. Also add what version of Excel. I am seeing Excel today supports 1 million plus rows even when exporting to CSV. Include exactly what steps you took, and what error message you got. I do not use Macs or old versions of excel. Horaciux provides a good workaround: break it into pieces  - fine for a one-time but not good if you need a scalable solution. Mysql may be breaking if you are not specifying quoted text.